# remote desktop services, cannot RDP to session host, always get gateway

Tags: remote-access, rdp, remote-desktop-services

I have RDS setup as
1 server hosting broker, web access, and gateway
2 servers as session hosts in a farm called farm1.

Remoteapps work fine. So does the RDP app on the in the remoteapp list.

However whenever I RDP from externally, I always get the gateway server rather than being load balanced to the session hosts in the farm. Any ideas why that is? I cannot figure out where to configure this. I think I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you launching the Remote Desktop Client and typing in the name of the gateway server? Because that's the only way you'd get the gateway server.

What you need to do is type in the name of the farm, and then click Options and on the Advanced tab turn on the Gateway option and type in the name of the gateway server there.

Comment: Ha... I am idiot, thank you. That is exactly what is needed.